# Migrate MCMS 2002 to SharePoint 2016

Tags: migration, 2016

We have an old farm with Microsoft content management system 2002!

We have decided to move to SharePoint 2016.

How can we migrate the data ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first be aware of the MCMS 2002 is not a supported edition for upgrading to SharePoint 2016! For more details check, [Review supported editions and products for upgrading to SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/b1088a52-179f-4120-8fb5-0ed3e6c088b1(v=office.16).aspx)

---

**So you should**

- [Upgrade from MCMS 2002 to SharePoint 2007](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261812%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), then
- [Upgrade from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/09/migrate-from-moss-2007-to-sharepoint-2010.html#ixzz4v6WTwSOv), then
- [Upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493272%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), finally
- [Upgrade from SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303420(v=office.16).aspx).

**Actually,** it's very long trip to upgrade/migrate from MCMS 2002 to SharePoint 2016!

So to accelerate this long process, I suggest to [Upgrade from MCMS 2002 to SharePoint 2007](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261812%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) then Migrate from SP 2007 to SP 2016 using a 3rd party Migration tool like:

- [Sharegate](https://get.share-gate.com/migration-sharepoint-2007-2013?gclid=CjwKCAjw3_HOBRBaEiwAvLBbohFsQZ6br5YHdP5ia7QDI_K6lqczv0VcLeF3_nLXoTK1qd4kEd4bwRoC4RMQAvD_BwE)
- [Metalogix](https://www.metalogix.com/blog/move-sharepoint-2010-to-2016)
- [AvePoint](https://www.avepoint.com/)
- [Saketa Migrator](https://saketa.com/migrator/)